# Website hosted on Amazon EC2 instance not accessible from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a running(Windows OS) Amazon EC2 instance. Just to check whether, I can host a website and access it from outside, I created a index.html file with the message 'Hello World!!', and hosted it using http-server on port 80. I can access this website using localhost. However, I am not able to access the website from my personal laptop. I am using Public DNS to access the website, I have also tried with public ip.

In security group, I have opened inbound traffic for HTTP & HTTPS both for all IPs. I can ping this instance from my laptop using the public DNS. 
**I am not sure, what else is missing ?**

Comment: Hi ,
Which server are you using to host this index.html? and have you opened the inbound for 8080?

Comment: Can you show what rules you have in your security group/

Comment: Verify that windows firewall allows this traffic in, if it is enabled.

Comment: The issue was the firewall. I added an inbound rule in firewall settings to allow http traffic. Now, it works fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

I would open all traffic to all IPs, clear your DNS cache, and make 100% sure that your security group is assigned to the correct instance.

Once you get that to work, then reduce it back down to http/s only.

If you are in a VPC, then then check your access control lists.  Is the subnet a public subnet?

Check your Windows Firewall settings.  This can be overlooked.

Comment: I allowed inbound traffic of tcp packets on port 80. This resolved the issue. Thanks !